# How to use JabRef with neovim without the --servername option?

Tags: neovim, clientserver

I'm using vim with latex to create documents and I insert references using JabRef and create a bibliography.

I can't use `--servername` in neovim (needed for JabRef).

Any suggestions on how to make neovim work with JabRef?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how [JabRef](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref) is related to Vim? Are you using some plugin? Either way support for the clientserver feature – which implements `--servername` – was removed in Neovim. This feature will have to be rewritten using Neovim's msgpack API

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
JabReb is a bibliographic software that pushes the latex citations to vim (or other editors). At any rate, it seems that I'll go back to vim for latex (using JabRef).

Comment: You could try neovim remote. It allows the remote options for neovim through an external script, nvr.